# Multiple fitnesse fixtures possible

Tags: fitnesse

Is it possible to use multiple fitnesse fixture classes in one testtable (a scriptable i.e.) as in something like the following?

```
|script|FixtureClassOne,FixtureClassTwo|
|AMethodInFixtureClassOne|2|
|AMethodInFixtureClassTwo|2|
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible. You should load the fixture as a library. E.g.:

```
| import |
| my.fixtures.classpath |

| library |
| fixture 1 |
| another fixture |

| script |
| etc. |
```

No need to provide a fixture after the 'script' identifier anymore.

You do have to be aware that if the fixtures share non-unique method names you get into trouble

Answer (score 0):

Objective: To have Multiple Fixtures associated with a single HTML Test Case

How: As you are working with fitnesses HTML Test case, you probably have at least a single fixture associated with it, which we will call default Fixture.

But in order to access another fixture (where control of execution passes to the other fixture), write a method in the default fixture class:

```
public Fixture run(String str) {
    try {
        Fixture fixture = Fixture.loadFixture(str);
        return fixture;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // put your error handling here
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

From the Test case, pass the fully specified location with the project to the `run()` method. When the `run()` method returns the fixture to the HTML test case, it passes its execution via the new Fixture.